# Does RingCentral fax support Expect: 100-continue header?

Tags: php, http, fax, ringcentral

I'm receiving a 400 error from the fax endpoint using the PHP SDK.

```
Exception: 400 Bad Request (and additional error happened during JSON parse: \
Response is not JSON) SDK HTTP Error at \
https://platform.ringcentral.com/restapi/v1.0/account/~/extension/~/fax
```

We are sending an `Expect: 100-continue` header. Could this be the issue?

We are running on AWS inside a Linux Docker system as in PHP code, MySQL DB and Apache webserver.

Comment: It's possible that your server is sending back a `100 Continue` status before the real status, and the SDK is not capable to handle multiple response headers. Dig into the SDK source to see what's really going on though

Answer (score 0):

I have never dealt with Expect 100 Continue header. I am not aware of if RingCentral API supports it or not. Why don't you just disable or not sending the 100 Continue header to see if it works. Also try with other simple endpoint such as sending an SMS or reading the call log to see if your environment is up and run well.

If that does not work, can you post a few line of code where you use the PHP SDK to call the Fax API.

Comment: I've explicitly sent `Expect: 100-continue` header with cURL and it works with the RingCentral fax API, using the FAQ commands. Apparently cURL automatically sends this as well. Next step is investigate PHP SDK more per Evert's comment above.